# ajax is not sending data to php through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**JS**

```js
function myFunction() {
    var query = '?';
    var str = $("form").serialize();
    var x = $("#results").text(query += str);
    return x;
}
$("input[type='sel'], input[type='text']").on("click", myFunction);
$("select").on("change", myFunction);

//window.alert(myFunction());


var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myFunction);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'insert_value.php',
    data: {
        data: jsonString
    },
    cache: false,

    success: function () {
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

**insert_value.php**

```php
<?php
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

  // here i would like use foreach:

  foreach($data as $d){
     echo $d;
  }


$src1= $_POST['data'];
$array = explode(",", $src1);

print_r($array);


  ?>
```

Here I have written java script for generating query string  and I'm passing that array into ajax to send that array to php and print the values

Here in case only query string is generating but not sending it to php using ajax

Comment: i think your ajax url is incorrect. it should be like `localhost/insert_value.php`

Comment: return str;   instead of return x;

Comment: @Chinito nope it can be a relative link

Comment: no it me gives error like this localhost:8083/insert_value.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: no need that question mark concatenation

Comment: have you tried running your php file on the url?

Comment: I want to insert those array value into a table after sending it to the php so I have concatenated the ? mark  into query string , without that also can I achieve insertion query in php?

Comment: yaa I have tried to run php file on the browser it came blank

Answer (score 2):

change your `myFunction` like this .***variable declaration was wrong*** .so my function not returning serialize data

```
 function myFunction() {
     var query = '?';
     var str = $("form").serialize();
     $("#results").text(query += str);
     var x = $("#results").text();
     return x;
 }
```

And

change the

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myFunction)
```

to

```
 var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myFunction());
```

**Working example**

```js
var obj = {
name:$('#name').val(),
age:$('#age').val(),
one:$('#one').val(),
two:$('#two').val(),
three:$('#three').val(),
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input value="hi" id="name" name="one">
  <input value="hi"  id="age" name="one">
  <input value="hi"  id="one" name="one">
  <input value="hi" id="two" name="one">
  <input value="hi"  id="three" name="one">

</form>
<p id="results"></p>
```

Comment: but what about ajax

Comment: @ShrutiAkki ajax was right. change the `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myFunction)` to `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myFunction());`   Define `myfunction()` *`add ()`* is function in json stringify .Try this

Comment: add your Ajax script  and `Json.stringify` into `$(document).ready(function(){ var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myFunction());
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'insert_value.php',
    data: {
        data: jsonString
    },
    cache: false,

    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
}); })` .

Comment: php file is `blank or have some data` .Kindly check with `console.log(data)` .Refer last comment code . it working on my local host .[`see this image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpSJo.png)

Comment: console.log(data) data is printing on the console

Comment: yes .. you could verify the data passing or not to the php .Its show the  `print_r($array);` in the console.log.press with `F12` show in the `console.log` . see=> https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpSJo.png

Comment: here it is taking data from dropdown control but not from textbox

Comment: you are correct in console its not showing any value and only dropdown deafault  value is showing not the changed value and text box value also empty  so what should I do for this

Comment: Check  your are  placing `name` attribute *(`name="something"`)* in your textbox . just like my snippet answer `<input value="hi" name="one">` => `name="one"`

Comment: I can't do like that because in my case is different i mean the name of text box will be changing dynamically

Comment: ok..But  the `$("form").serialize();` will assign the key value of the Json using `name` attribute.Its a default behaviour

Comment: hmmm... thn what I shoud do now

Comment: better you could create object with  all the element  like => `var obj={name:$('yourelementclass|id').val(),age:$('yourelementclass|id').val()}` .Then pass this obj to `JSON.stringify(obj)`

Comment: see my updated snippet.i was created object with input value.For more understanding search with google .lots of the example already there with object create